# Time complexity of nested for loop function involving mod to filter out the execution

Tags: algorithm-analysis, runtime-analysis, loops

I have to find the time complexity of the following program:

```
function(int n)
{
    for(int i=0;i<n;i++)                   //O(n) times
        for(int j=i;j<i*i;j++)             //O(n^2) times
            if(j%i==0)
            {  //O(n) times
                for(int k=0;k<j;k++)       //O(n^2) times
                    printf("8");
            }
}
```

I analysed this function as follows:

```
i : O(n)  : 1        2        3          4             5
j :       : 1        2..3     3..8       4..15         5..24           (values taken by j)
    O(n^2): 1        2        6          12            20              (Number of times executed)
j%i==0    : 1        2        3,6        4,8,12        5,10,15,20      (Values for which the condition is true)
    O(n)  : 1        1        2          3             4
k         : 1        2        3,6        4,8,12        5,10,15,20      (Number of times printf is executed)
    Total : 1        2        9          24            50              (Total)
```

However I am unable to bring about any conclusions since I don't find any correlation between $i$ which is essentially $O(n)$ and Total of k (last line). In fact I don't understand if we should be looking at the time complexity in terms of number of times `printf` is executed since that will neglect $O(n^2)$ execution of j-for loop. The answer given was $O(n^5)$ which I presume is wrong but then whats correct?

Comment: You may be interested in our [reference question](http://cs.stackexchange.com/questions/23593/is-there-a-system-behind-the-magic-of-algorithm-analysis), and other questions on [tag:algorithm-analysis+loops].

Comment: Are you interested in upper and/or lower bounds, or exact figures? You'll need to figure out how many multiples of $i$ are between $i$ and $i^2$ -- that's not too hard.

Comment: Anything will help...I am just not able to proceed from here.

Comment: If there is no specific question, I think this is a duplicate of the reference question. Look at the rules for loops there and go at it step by step!

Comment: I do not feel my question was not clear...but anyways I want to know how it is $O(n^5)$

Comment: The problem I was facing that there is this `if(j%i=0)` condition which does not make this question straight forward evaluation of the loop time complexity. I am unable to figure out how this condition is affecting the overall runtime complexity of the function. Thus not able to come up with any bound.

Comment: So you try to find asymptotic complexity with small numbers? This cannot work. If you cannot count complexity looking at the loops then look at the reference question. To count it from the code - replace printf with counter variable, run it for bigger numbers (several digits) and fit polynomials up to fifth order (if you assume that might be the case). Oh, how do you mod by 0?